# Replace an entire string using regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I would like it to look something like this.

```
my $str = 'axxxx';

my $replacement = 'string_begins_with_a';

$str =~ s/^a/$replacement/;

print "$str\n"; #should print 'string_begins_with_a'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to consume the rest of the line by adding `.*` after `a`:

```
my $str = 'axxxx';
my $replacement = 'string_begins_with_a';
$str =~ s/^a.*/$replacement/;
print "$str\n"; #prints 'string_begins_with_a'
```

Or, you may just check if `$str` starts with `a`, and then assign the `$replacement` value to it:

```
$str = ($str =~ /^a/) ? $replacement : $str;
```

or just

```
if ($str =~ /^a/) {
    $str = $replacement;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this answer is useful too!

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was not aware that you posted yours half a minute earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Match the whole string with a `^a.*` regex and then replace it using your replacement string.

```
$str =~ s/^a.*/$replacement/;
print "$str\n"; # would print 'string_begins_with_a'
```

Comment: Thanks this what I was looking for!

Comment: I do not say you copied from my answer, but that it contains just the same solution. I know that SO has some lags displaying answers.